# Can't mount device

Tags: linux, debian, mount, ntfs

everybody!
I have a strange problem.
When i try to mount hard drive or usb flash i see the strange messages in syslog.
And i can't rw on my device.
What the stange thing is happened?
I use Debian 8.0 jessie.

```
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.940656] scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 8GB    8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.941481] sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.942581] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] 15687680 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.943091] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.943093] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.943586] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.943588] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.946315] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.946317] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.969534]  sdh: sdh1
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.972151] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.972153] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Feb  9 16:38:33 qch kernel: [23786.972155] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch ntfs-3g[15610]: Version 2014.2.15AR.2 integrated FUSE 28
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch ntfs-3g[15610]: Mounted /dev/sdh1 (Read-Write, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch ntfs-3g[15610]: Cmdline options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177,uhelper=udisks2
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch ntfs-3g[15610]: Mount options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdh1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch ntfs-3g[15610]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch udisksd[4009]: Mounted /dev/sdh1 at /media/rexer/Debian 7.8.0 amd64 1 on behalf of uid 1000
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1413]: index_parse.c:191: indx_parse(): error opening /media/rexer/Debian 7.8.0 amd64 1/BDMV/index.bdmv
Feb  9 16:38:34 qch org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1413]: index_parse.c:191: indx_parse(): error opening /media/rexer/Debian 7.8.0 amd64 1/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
```

Comment: What message do you get when you attempt to write to the device?

Comment: When i try to enter on my usb, for example, from nautilus, the error message with "error input/output" shows
pcmanfm shows the "current directory is not right"

Comment: Can you access the device using the console?

Comment: I can mount it by sudo, but i can't read and write files from it.
But i can enter to device, if i mount it by console.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo mount`

Comment: nothing, it seems like everything is allright, but it doesn't

Comment: `sudo mount` produces no output? I wonder if you have a problem with STDOUT being redirected somewhere it shouldn't.

Comment: there is no output, and i do not redirect stdout.
mount /dev/sdh1 /mnt/flash - that command i use.

Comment: I meant the output of just `sudo mount` so we can see if the device is mounted read only.

Answer (score 0):

Just searched for the syslog error:

> org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1562]: index_parse.c:191: indx_parse(): error opening [...]/BDMV/index.bdmv

and found this interesting thread - [[SOLVED] Arch treats drives as bluray? Error opening bdmv in journal](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176294).

It says there's a problem with gvfs and libbluray, and building gvfs with a few changes to disable bluray support fixes it. Arch-oriented, but should be similar in Debian or anything that uses gvfs. Just removing libbluray should work too, but...

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1375433#p1375433

  > Ok - I have removed the libbluray like advised and after reboot the
  >   issue was gone. Removing it however kills mencoder, mplayer and
  >   possibly few other packages... Will try to compile libbluray and see
  >   what happens...
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1375419#p1375419

  > I think that gvfs may also be to blame, as it does provide
  >   UDisks2VolumeMonitor. You can build it without bluray support by
  >   passing --disable-bluray to the configure script.
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1375800#p1375800

  > The source package is from the ABS, and the only modified thing is the
  >   PKGBUILD. There's no gvfs source code in this package, it's being
  >   downloaded from the official website when you run makepkg. If you
  >   don't trust it, you can get the package source from ABS and add
  >   --disable-bluray to the configure params in PKGBUILD yourself or run a diff on my PKGBUILD and the official one. Look at the file list of
  >   gvfs: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/gvfs/ It provides
  >   /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor.service
  >   and /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor, and your logs show:
  >   org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor. The UDisks2VolumeMonitor seems
  >   to be responsible for detecting storage devices and providing info
  >   about them to desktop environments. The fact that mount seems to cause
  >   the problem may be because the UDisks2VolumeMonitor can be constantly
  >   monitoring the mountpoints, to check for example, if a disk is
  >   mounted.

I'm not positive if it'll fix this exact error aarexer has (needed more info) but should be helpful to anyone else searching for the same syslog error.